# Unable to call Node Server API using href="" after implementing $locationProvider

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, location-provider

I am a junior dev so I apologize if I say anything incorrectly or am not clear on my explanations. I am creating a MEAN stack application, and all of the routing is working correctly when I put `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` on my config and I also added

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/public' });
});
```

to my index.js on the server side, and `<base href="/"></base>` on my index.html.

The problem is, on my html views, I have hrefs that connect to my server, and when I click on them, instead of calling the api, it will take me to localhost/api/..., which then redirects me back to the login page because it does not exist. (I am using passport local). When I remove $locationprovider and the rest of the above code, the hrefs work like they should.

Here is the example:

`<a href="/connect/instagram"</a>`     is listed on one of my views. This is supposed to take me to instagrams website so that I can authorize my account. When using $locationProvider, it takes me to localhost/connect/instagram, which doesn't exist, and therefore boots me out to the login page since that route doesn't exist.

I have tried removing the'/' in front of connect/instagram, and no luck. I am stuck at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, to clarify: you want to use html5Mode, but you want to access `/connect/instagram` without treating it as an angular route?

Comment: Can you provide the `angular.config(...)` code? What that means is please post the the code that you are using `locationProvider` and `html5Mode(true)`.

Comment: @wil93 Thanks so much! Worked perfectly!